# How to create stacked ensemble of U-Net models with different input shapes

Tags: tensorflow, computer-vision, semantic-segmentation

I'm trying to create stacked ensemble of U-Net models with different input shapes and I'm wondering if my solution is correct.

So let's say i have 2 U-Net (generally it will be N) with input/output shapes:

- U-Net1: height: 500, width: 500
- U-Net2: height: 600, width: 600

And I would like to build stacked ensemble model to output predicted mask with the shape:
height: 550, width: 550.

My simplified idea for the neural network uses `Resizing()` layers:

```
submodels = [U_Net1, U_Net2]
n_class = 5

inputs = [submodel.input for submodel in submodels]
outputs = [submodel.output for submodel in submodels]
outputs = [Resizing(height=550, width=550)(o) for o in outputs]
merge = Concatenate()(outputs)
output = Conv2D(..., padding="same") # Some convolutional layers - multiple
output = Conv2D(filters=n_class, kernel_size=(1, 1), activation="softmax")(output)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=output, name="ensemble")
```

It is clear to my that the `inputs` of this network will be original images resized accordingly with the same augmentation for both nets. As the `output` I have two options:

- original mask resized to 550x550 applied with the same augmentation as `inputs`
- original mask resized twice accordingly to U-Nets with same augmentation as `inputs`. Then those two masks will be resized to 550x550 and majority voting will be applied to create final mask

I would like to know what output will be correct in this case and is my network architecture sufficient? Thank you in advance for help.